# Skip upload sources in gradle plugin for maven

Tags: java, android, maven, jar, aar

I'm using [THIS](http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html) guide for uploading an Android library (aar) to maven using gradle:

But I noticed it also uploads the source files. I'm not allowed to publish the sources of that project.

How can I skip the sources upload?

Note: Tried commenting this lines in the script

```
    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
            classifier = 'sources'
            from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }

    artifacts {
            archives androidSourcesJar
    }
```

But if I do that it uploads nothing to the repo

Comment: Does the issue solved ?